# Save Key Value pairs from ruby Hash to a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, database

"I have developed a script that takes a json file and takes specific values from inside of it and saves them as key-value pairs in a ruby hash. Now that I have all the values i needed from the file stored in a hash, is there a method I can use to save said key-value pairs in a sql server database?

The following is the way I have the information I need stored in a hash."

```
client_info = {
   "Name" => fullName,
   "BirthDate" => birthDate,
   "MemberId" => memberId
}
```

Comment: Use an [ActiveRecord serializer](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize). As simple as adding `serialize :field, JSON` to the relevant model. Rails will serialize the hash to JSON, store it in the db as a string, and when you fetch the value it'll serialize the JSON back to a hash.

Answer (score 0):

If all records are going to have (more or less) the same structure, I would recommend not storing the serialized JSON and explicitly describe in the table structure the columns that are going to be needed.

However, if you really do need to store the hash in the SQL server I would recommend using a [JSON column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) instead of a string. Among other features, this will allow you to use indexes on some keys of the hash.